# problema con consulta MySQL de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql, join

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un problema con la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT h.sexo,
       h.universidad, 
       count(*) as TOTALES, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.universidad = 'Latina' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number,
       SUM(CASE WHEN h.universidad = 'UAM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numbers
from citas as u 
join pacientes as h
  on u.cedulaFK = h.cedula 
  AND u.fecha_cita >= '$fecha1' and u.fecha_cita <= '$fecha2'
where u.cod_sedeFK = 1
ORDER BY h.sexo
```

quiero mostrar la cantidad de citas por sexo o género, además de la universidad a la que pertenecen. Pero solo me esta mostrando la cantidad de citas de un solo sexo, omitiendo los demás

Comment: Proba poniendo un group by h.sexo, h.universidad

Comment: en tu pregunta dices que 3 tablas y solo muestras 2 tablas puedes exponer como creaste citas y pacientes? porque solo colocas where codigo sede =1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un `GROUP BY` en el sexo.

```
SELECT 
    p.sexo,
    p.universidad, 
    COUNT(*) as TOTALES, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.universidad = 'Latina' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS number,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.universidad = 'UAM' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS numbers
FROM citas as c 
    JOIN pacientes as p
        ON c.cedulaFK = p.cedula 
        AND c.fecha_cita >= '$fecha1' -- Esto no podría ir dentro del WHERE?
        AND c.fecha_cita <= '$fecha2' -- Junto con esto?
WHERE 
    c.cod_sedeFK = 1
GROUP BY 
    p.sexo, p.universidad -- agrupas por sexo y universidad
```